# Flutter how to hide system navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

How to hide system navigation bar in flutter? I have tried hiding it with

```
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
 overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

But when ever a touch happens on the app, the system navigation popups first. I need to only display the statusbar. How can I turnoff the system navigation bar ?

[image]

Comment: See this answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69115166/in-flutter-2-5-in-android-full-screen-lean-back-sticky-sticky-immersive-and-e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide android's bottom navigation bar in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365173/how-to-hide-androids-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **setEnabledSystemUIMode** and provide **SystemUiMode.manual** as shown below:

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [ SystemUiOverlay.top ]);`